Existence of inf(A)
In my analysis textbook, the definition of a "complete" set is as follows: Let $S$ be an ordered field. Then $S$ is complete if $sup(A) \in S$ for every nonempty $A \subseteq S$ where $A$ is bounded above. It is left as an exercise to show the existence of greatest lower bounds. Here is my unfinished attempt (I want to show that $inf(A) = -sup(-A)$ as suggested by the book):
Suppose $S$ is complete, and $A \subseteq S$ is nonempty and bounded below.
Then $-A \subseteq S$ is also nonempty and bounded above.
So, $\exists c_0 \in S$ st $c_0 \geq x$ $\forall x \in -A$ and $c_0 \leq c$ for all other upper bounds $c$
$c_0 \geq x$ for all $x \in -A$ implies $-c_0 \leq -x$ for all $-x \in A$.
Hence, $c_0$ is a lower bound for $A$.
Now, if $c$ is an arbitrary upper bound for $-A$, $c \geq x$ $\forall x \in -A$
So, $-c_0 \leq -x$ $\forall -x \in A$.
Also, we knew from before that $c_0 \leq c$, so $-c_0 \geq -c$
This means $-c_0 = -sup(-A) = inf(A)$.
My issue is that I never was able to show that if every lower bound is of the form $-c$ where $c$ is an upper bound of A, so the logic from the 2nd to last line to the last line of the proof seems faulty. Also, my textbook has not yet stated that being bounded below implies the existence of $inf(A)$ so I can't start the proof with "let $α=inf(A)$ as was done in another post of a similar problem.
Thanks in advance!

This post will help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438346/proving-sup-b-inf-a

@KijeongLim I looked at the post, but they assumed that the inf(A) exists, which is part of what I am trying to prove. I'm not sure how to prove the existence of inf(A).

If $A$ is bounded below, then $-A$ is bounded above (why?).  So by completeness $\sup (-A)$ exists.  So $-\sup(-A)$ exists  (because $S$ is a field).  Don't assume that $\inf A$ exists, but prove that $-\sup(-A)$ satisfies all the defintion requirements of $\inf A$ and that therefore by definition $-\sup(-A) = \inf A$.

See...... Suppose I was asked to prove that $-3-2=-5$ but I didn't know that $-5$ exists at all.  I'd prove it by noting that $5 + (-3-2) = (5+(-3))+(-2)=2 +(-2) = 0$.  The as the definition of $-5$ is the number $x$ so that $5+x =0$ and $5+(-3-2) =0$ then $(-3-2)$ satisfies the definition, I can conclude that, not only, does $-5$ exist, that it must be $-3 -2$.  .... Okay, that a little silly but that's the same reasoning you need to use to prove $\inf A$ exists.  For that something that you already know exist satisfies what you mean by $\inf A$ and therefore it has to be $\inf A$.

"So, ∃c0∈S st c0≥x ∀x∈−A and c0≤c for all other upper bounds c" Why be oscure/obtuse.  Just say instead.  "So $\sup(-A)\in S$ and let $c_0 = \sup(-A)$.  "Hence, c0 is a lower bound for A." Is this a typo?  $-c_0$ is a lower bound for $A$.  "Now, if c is an arbitrary upper bound for −A, c≥x ∀x∈−A"  Nix this.  Don't worry about arbitrary upper bounds of $-A$.  Worry about whether $-c_0$ is greatest lower bound of $A$.  Let $d$ be so that $-c_0 < d$ then $-d < c_0 =\sup(-A)$ so ..... can you finish?  ... to be continued....

... cont...."My issue is that I never was able to show that if every lower bound is of the form −c where c is an upper bound of A" You don't have to (although you can).  Just show if $-c_0 < d$ then $-d < c_0 =\sup(-A)$ so ...

""My issue is that I never was able to show that if every lower bound is of the form −c where c is an upper bound of A" If you really want to do that then just do that.  If $d$ is a lower bound of $A$ the for all $a\in A$, $d\le a$.  So for any $b \in -A$ the $b=-a$ for some $a\in A$. So $d \le a$ so $-d \ge -a =b$.  So $-d$ is an upper bound of $-A$.  And $d =-(-d)$ where $-d$ is an upper bound of $-A$.  Done.

Let $A \subseteq S$ be a nonempty set which is bounded below.
Take $$ {A}{\downarrow} := \left\{ x \in S | \left( \forall a \in A \right) \left( x \leq a \right) \right\} . $$
We'll show ${A}{\downarrow}$ has a supremum in $S$.

Since $A$ is bounded below,
there exists $c \in S$ s.t. $\left( \forall a \in A \right) \left( c \leq a \right)$.
So, ${A}{\downarrow}$ is nonempty.

Since $A$ is nonempty, there exists $a_0 \in A$.
Hence, ${A}{\downarrow}$ is bounded above by $a_0$.


Thus ${A}{\downarrow}$ has a supremum in $S$, say $i$.
To prove $i$ is the infimum of $A$,
it is enough to show
$$ \left( \forall \ell \in S \right) \left[ i \ge \ell \leftrightarrow \left( \forall a \in A \right) \left( a \ge \ell \right) \right] \quad \cdots \, (*) . $$
Lemma P. Let $R$ be a binary relation of a set $X$. Then, $R$ is a preorder if and only if $$ \left( \forall x \in X \right) \left( \forall y \in X \right) \left[ x R y \leftrightarrow \left( \forall z \in X \right) \left( z R x \to z R y \right) \right] . $$
To prove $(*)$, let $\ell$ be an arbitrary element of $S$.

Proof of ($\Rightarrow$).


Assume $i \ge \ell$ and $a \in A$. Then our goal is to show $a \ge \ell$.
Since $i \ge \ell$, $\left( \forall z \in A \right) \left( z \ge i \to z \ge \ell \right)$ holds by lemma P.
Since $a$ is an upper bound of ${A}{\downarrow}$, $a \ge i$ holds.
By 2 and 3, $a \ge \ell$ holds by the definition of $\sup \left( {A}{\downarrow} \right)$.


Proof of ($\Leftarrow$).


Assume $\left( \forall a \in A \right) \left( a \ge \ell \right)$.
Then our goal is to show $i \ge \ell$.
By 5, $\ell$ is a lowerbound of $A$, that is, $\ell \in {A}{\downarrow}$.
Thus $\ell \le i$ holds by the definition of $\sup \left( {A}{\downarrow} \right)$.

So we can conclude that $i$ is the infimum of $A$.

I think your $A \downarrow$ is better without space ${A}{\downarrow}$.

@GEdgar Please touch them, instead of me. I don't know how to replace.

Done.  To avoid the spacing, use {A}{\downarrow}.  Normally, \downarrow is considered to be a binary operation, and spaced accordingly.
